# silverlight: setting RowDetailsTemplate controls from RowDetailsVisibilityChanged

Tags: silverlight

Given a silverlight datagrid with RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected", on clicking a row in the datagrid, how do you set or bind the controls in the RowDetailsVisibilityChanged() event?

```
        <data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="a" x:Name="_txt" />
                    <ListBox x:Name="_lst"></ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code the rowsvisibilitychanged event, Silverlight will do the binding for you automatically if you set up binding in your data template.  Simply use {Binding col_name}.

A simplified example, binding happens automatically as user clicks a row.

```
<sdk:DataGrid RowDetailsVisibilityMode='VisibleWhenSelected'
              ItemsSource='{Binding ElementName=ld_linkDomainDataSource, Path=Data}'>

<data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text='Link Name: '/>
                <TextBox Text='{Binding link_name}'/>   <-- column from ItemsSource
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```